# What is the equivalent of RACCommand in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, events, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have a View and a View Model. The View contains a button, and every time the user presses it, I want the View Model to be informed. I also want a second View Model to be informed when the first view model gets the event.

So the tap event would be propagated as follows:

```
Button -> ViewModel1 -> ViewModel2
```

I could design this by binding `button.rx_tap` to `viewModel1.onButtonTapped()`, however since I want `viewModel2` to subscribe to also get the event, I need some kind of observable that receives an action and propagates it. I believe that is what `RACCommand` does.

How can I implement this using RxSwift?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct equivalent of `RACCommand` now in the RxSwift itself.

However, there is a project in RxSwiftCommunity, called [Action](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/Action), which is inspired by `RACCommand`.

The creators of RxSwift in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/254) suggested that `ActivityIndicator` class can be used in some cases where `RACCommand` could be useful.